# import csv is not executing in pycharm

Tags: python, attributeerror

In my pycharm import csv is not working and my code is :

```
import csv

with open("names.csv", "r") as file:
    data = list(csv.reader(file))

print(data)
```

I tried Many times executing by changing some variables and all and I am getting the following error:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python course\practice\venv\csv.py", line 1, in <module>
    import csv
  File "D:\Python course\practice\venv\csv.py", line 4, in <module>
    data = list(csv.reader(file))
                ^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: partially initialized module 'csv' has no attribute 'reader' (most likely due to a circular import)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your script is picking a local file named `csv` over the builtin `csv`, name your local file something else

Answer (score 1):

Your error shows a file named "csv.py". When attempting to import the package "csv", Python is getting confused and trying to import your local file called "csv.py". Just change the name of that file and it will be fixed.